# Do I need 2 licenses for staging and production

Tags: license

Or is one pro license enough? We're running a stage environment and a production environment for the same website. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

One is enough you don't need a license for a development server at all [source](https://craftcms.com/support/license-enforcement)

And here is something from FAQ as well [link](https://craftcms.com/pricing)

> **Is there a way I can try Craft Client or Pro out before buying?**
>   
> Yes. As long as you’re running Craft CMS from a non-public-looking domain name (e.g. “mysite.dev” or “staging.mysite.com”), you will have the option to test the Client and Pro editions indefinitely.

And a info from the [Terms and Conditions](https://craftcms.com/license)

> **3. License Agreement Model**
>   This is a single-installation license, meaning you may integrate a Licensed Copy into one public-facing (“Internet”) or internal (“intranet”) web root directory at a time (the “Website”). **You may also install and use Craft without limitation for local development and testing purposes.**